# object is not callable error in Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.2, callable

Good evening,

EDIT:  This question was answered, much appreciation for all interest.

I am a student working on an assignment and I have run into an error I cannot seem to shake out.

I am trying to use a function to run several other functions in sequence to play a game.  many of the 'helper functions' were provided by the instructor and I cannot alter them, there are several other functions I have defined which appear to work alone, however, when I put them together it comes back with an error complaining that I'm trying to call an object that isn't eligible.

Here is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        playBingo()
      File "C:\Users\SerTorm\Documents\School\PSU\CS 161\Projects\Homework\HW5\Homework5.py", line 161, in playBingo
        cover = cover(numbers,log,num)
    TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure how much of the code you want to see, it's a fairly long file.  Perhaps the definition that is creating the error would do it..?

```
    def playBingo():
"""  Use the given and manufactured functions to play a game of Bingo. """

initializeCaller()
card = newBingoCard()
cover = newBlankCover()
bingo = ''
while not bingo:
    printCardAndCover(card,cover)
    called = nextCall()
    cover = cover(card,cover,called[1])
    if bingoRow(cover) or bingoColumn(cover) or bingoDiagonal(cover):
        bingo = 1
print('Bingo!')
```

And I suppose if anyone wants to read it, I can try to post more of it.  I just gave it a couple minutes and when I try to copy in long patches of code the code block formatting seemed to get wonky and difficult to read, so I won't do that just yet.

Thanks for any comments, have a good evening.

Torm

Comment: Do you have a function called cover? You are possibly shadowing it with a variable with the same name - cover.

Comment: Can you show us what `newBlankCover` is?

Comment: `cover = cover(card,cover,called[1])` will overwrite the function `cover`! You probably don't want that. Use a different name, i.e. `cover_result = cover(...)`.

Comment: FogleBird:  Thank you very much, that is what did it, I worked with the variable names and now it let's me past.  Now I have to figure out how to mark the question as answered...

Comment: You'll have to wait until he add an answer.